# Ansi c preprocessor: Can I concatenate macro name and argument into single variable name?

Tags: c, macros, ansi-c

I'd like to shorten variable names, so instead of this :
FPData.Temps.T.Solar.Val

I'd like to use :

```
TEMP_Solar.Val
```

and define macro :

```
#define TEMP_  FPData.Temps.T.
```

But it works only if I put space in between :

```
TEMP_ Solar.Val
```

compiles ok, but I'd like to use this one

```
TEMP_Solar.Val
```

Possible? I know I could get around by using macro and arguments "TEMP_VAL(Solar)" but would like to keep it simple, linear concatenation...

Comment: Not sure that it is possible. What should the preprocessor do if you will write something like `_TEMP_DEFINE_`?

Comment: I think the '##' is the only way to make new identifiers/tokens in C or cpp or C++ source.

Comment: don't forget to _upclick_, **or** click the _answered_ check by any of these responses that work for you.

Comment: Why not use pointer instead? my_val_type *pval = &FPData.Temps.T.Solar.Val;

Answer (score 3):

It's because the preprocessor, which handles macros, only recognizes their own identifiers. When you use e.g. `TEMP_Solar` it's a different identifier from `TEMP_`.

The preprocessor might even use a simple `strcmp` to find its macros, so there can't be no sub-strings nor can there be differences in case.

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious and easy solution:

```
#define TEMP FPData.Temps.T

TEMP.Solar.Val
```

(You cannot and should not change the actual variable names of the struct members.)

Comment: @user2152780 if you want to say thanks, give up vote.